# What is the correct way to link a button to open an other py file?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a big doubt because my script is not performing as it should be. So I have a simple main file with a button that opens a blank grid (codes below). The problem with this code is that it opens reportWindow the first time it executes, but if I close the report and I  try to open it again I receive the error : 
NameError: name 'TestFrame' is not defined

I've also removed `if __name__ == '__main__'` from the last lines of reportWindow.py because the script wasn't working with it. I tried `if __name__ == 'main'` as it's imported from main.py but it didn't work either.

Please, can someone show me how it should have been done the correct way?

Thank you

**main.py**

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id, "Frame aka Window", size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label = "Exit", pos=(80, 80), size = (120,30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closebutton, button)

    def closebutton(self,event):
        from reportWindow import SimpleGrid
        SimpleGrid(TestFrame, -1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()  
    frame = Test(parent=None, id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

**reportWindow.py**

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid): ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        #[...Some code...]


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "Title", size=(1400,800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)

        #[...Some code...]


#if __name__ == '__main__':
import sys
from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectableApp
app = InspectableApp(False)
frame = TestFrame(None, sys.stdout)
frame.Show(True)
#import wx.lib.inspection
#wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few of issues.

**1)** The `NameError` is occurring because you're not importing `TestFrame` from `reportWindow`.

**2)** Without `if __name__ == "__main__"` in `reportWindow.py` your program will create another `wx.App` and start another `MainLoop` which will block the first loop from receiving events etc... You should only create 1 `App/MainLoop`.  It will also create the `TestFrame` the first time you import `reportWindow`.

**3)** It looks like you want `SimpleGrid` to be a child of `TestFrame`, but then you try to create it by itself in `closebutton`.

**4)** When creating the `SimpleGrid` you pass the `TestFrame` class instead of an instance of the `TestFrame` class.

Here is the modified code

```
# main.py
import wx, sys


class Test(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, "Frame aka Window", size=(300, 200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Exit", pos=(80, 80), size=(120, 30))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.closebutton, button)

    def closebutton(self, event):
        from reportWindow import TestFrame

        frame = TestFrame(self, sys.stdout)
        frame.Show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Test(parent=None, id=1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

---

```
# reportWindow.py
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib


class SimpleGrid(gridlib.Grid):  ##, mixins.GridAutoEditMixin):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        gridlib.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)

        # [...Some code...]


class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, log):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, 0, "Title", size=(1400, 800))
        self.grid = SimpleGrid(self, log)

        # [...Some code...]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    from wx.lib.mixins.inspection import InspectableApp

    app = InspectableApp(False)
    frame = TestFrame(None, sys.stdout)
    frame.Show(True)
    import wx.lib.inspection
    wx.lib.inspection.InspectionTool().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```